# How to check which row produces and error in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, error-handling

I am using complex UDF on string which has produced and error: `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.`

Is there a way to check which row produces and error - something like:

```
select 
UDF(arguments)
from tb
where 
IsError(UDF(arguments))=TRUE
```

Is there something like IsError to get such bad records?

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know.
Your best bet as I see it would be to do a cursor that can call the UDF for each row, and then you can capture the error per row.

So I'm thinking something like

(pseducode)

```
DECLARE CURSOR FOR YOUR TABLE
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    TRY UDF
    CATCH ERROR AND LOG
END

REPORT ALL ERRORS
```

(this is one of the few times a cursor is good in SQL because you need to handle each row individually)

Comment: I am not able to check it as I do not know cursors in SQL. Only vote up, but do not accept.